# Is it possible to combine a for loop with setTimeOut in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm clear doing something wrong here. All the letters print out at once. I want a typewriter effect within an HTML canvas. (Ultimately, I'd like the letters to follow a line traced within the canvas, but that's a larger puzzle.) I think the problem is in the for loop, but I'm not sure how to fix it... Any help appreciated!

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
canvas {
    border: 2px solid #f00;
}
</style>
</head>

<label>Your message here:</label>
<br>
<input class="textBox" style="width: 50em; height: 2em;"  id="userInput" />
<button id="sub_btn">Submit</button>

<body>
<canvas width="360" height="400" id="canvas"></canvas>

<script type="text/javascript"> 

var canvas, ctx;

function typeOut(str, startX, startY, lineHeight, padding) {
    var random = Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+40);
    var cursorX = startX || 0;
    var cursorY = startY || 0;
    var lineHeight = lineHeight || 32;
    padding = padding || 10;
    var i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i <= str.length; i++){

    var w = ctx.measureText(str.charAt(i)).width;
    if(cursorX + w >= canvas.width - padding) {
            cursorX = startX;
            cursorY += lineHeight;
        }

    if (str.charAt(i) === '\n' || str.charAt(i) === '\r'){
            ctx.fillText(str.charAt(i), cursorX, cursorY);
            setTimeout(typeOut, 20);
            cursorX = startX;
    } else if (str.charAt(i) === ' '){
            ctx.fillText(str.charAt(i), cursorX, cursorY);
            setTimeout(typeOut, 20);
            cursorX += w;
    } else if (str.charAt(i) === ',' || str.charAt(i) === '.' || str.charAt(i) === '?'){
            ctx.fillText(str.charAt(i), cursorX, cursorY);
            setTimeout(typeOut, 220);
            cursorX += w;
    } else if ( str.charAt(i) === '@') {
            ;
            setTimeout(typeOut, 300);
    } else {
            ctx.fillText(str.charAt(i), cursorX, cursorY);
            setTimeout(typeOut, random);
            cursorX += w;
    }
  }
}

(document.getElementById('sub_btn').onclick = function() {
    canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.fillStyle = '#000000';
    ctx.font = '24px sans-serif';
    var str = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
    typeOut(str, 25, 25, 32, 10 );

})();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You'll have to give more than 'doesn't work'. Does the console say anything? What's the expected vs actual output?

Comment: set up a live exemple on jsfiddle to illustrate your problem. The letters will print at once since for loop is synchronous but setTimeout is asynchronous , one solution would be to use the i value of the for loop to increase the delay of the timeout with each iteration

Comment: @tryingToGetProgrammingStraight It assigns `0` to `cursorX` if `startX` is falsey. @tremstat Use a recursive function (like you are almost doing with setTimeout) and not a loop. Pass the iterator along to the next call to the function after a delay, and just drop the for loop altogether.

Comment: @RUJordan, the expected output is a typewriter effect. The actual output is all the letters arriving at once. There are no "errors" that would appear in the console, setTimeOut is just not delaying the function.

Comment: @Chad thnx for ur help

Comment: Thanks, @Chad. Is this what you mean? http://jsfiddle.net/chrisvnicholson/pYXVk/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setTimeout()` isn't like a 'sleep' function. It doesn't pause the script. When you say:

```
setTimeout(typeOut, 220);
```

You're saying "Schedule another call to `typeOut()` in 220ms, and meanwhile keep going with the `for` loop as before.

You want to process a character, then call a continuation function (at the right interval) to process the next.  Something like:

```
function typeOut(str, startX, startY, lineHeight, padding) {
    var random = Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+40);
    var cursorX = startX || 0;
    var cursorY = startY || 0;
    var lineHeight = lineHeight || 32;
    padding = padding || 10;
    var i = 0;

    // this will be called once per character
    var processNext = function() {
      if (i >= str.length)
        return;
      var timeout = random;

      var w = ctx.measureText(str.charAt(i)).width;
      if(cursorX + w >= canvas.width - padding) {
            cursorX = startX;
            cursorY += lineHeight;
      }

      if (str.charAt(i) === '\n' || str.charAt(i) === '\r'){
            ctx.fillText(str.charAt(i), cursorX, cursorY);
            timeout = 20;
            cursorX = startX;
      } else if (str.charAt(i) === ' '){
            ctx.fillText(str.charAt(i), cursorX, cursorY);
            timeout = 20;
            cursorX += w;
      } else if (str.charAt(i) === ',' || str.charAt(i) === '.' || str.charAt(i) === '?'){
            ctx.fillText(str.charAt(i), cursorX, cursorY);
            timeout = 220;
            cursorX += w;
      } else if ( str.charAt(i) === '@') {
            timeout = 300;
      } else {
            ctx.fillText(str.charAt(i), cursorX, cursorY);
            cursorX += w;
      }

      ++i;

      setTimeout(processNext, timeout);
    };

    // now start typing
    processNext();
}
```

Example CodePen: http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/EDqok

Comment: @tremstat You may also want to track the timeOuts in a variable, so you can cancel the drawing by calling `clearTimeout()`.